# the Eval function in Python

Tags: python, eval

Hello there i have the following code:

path = some destination on your harddrive

```
def K(path):
    try:

        getfile = open(path + '/test.txt')
        line = getfile.readlines()
        print line
        getfile.close()

    except:
        line = getfile.readlines()
        eval(line)
        d = dict()
        val= d[k]
```

to import a textfile, now my problem is to avoid the `\n`, which i assume can be done using the `eval()` function. I want to convert the string i get as input, to floats i can work with..

Thanx for any tips in advance

Comment: It would help if you describe the format of your text file. Using `eval` to avoid `\n` is something indescribable.

Comment: What is this code supposed to do?

Comment: it takes some file.txt on my harddrive and imports the text to python shell as a string, so if the file for instant had 1,2 (newline) 2,3 (newline) 7,5 the input i get in shell is ['1,2\n', '2,3\n', '7,5'] and i want it to be numbers i can work with :) hope that helped

Comment: ... So let's be clear: each line int the file has, as text, a comma-delimited list of integers on it, and you want to convert this text into a Python list of `int` objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't comment your code, just will post an example you can examine and modify to get it working. This function reads the content of a text file and converts tokens separated by whitespaces to floats if possible:

```
def getFloats(filepath):
  fd = open(filepath) # open the file
  try:
    content = fd.read().split() # read fully
    def flo(value):  # a function that returns a float for the given str or None
      try: return float(value)
      except ValueError: return None # skip invalid values
    # iterate through content and make items float or None,
    # iterate over the result to choose floats only
    return [x for x in [flo(y) for y in content] if x]
  finally:
    fd.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

```
>>> float("\n1234\n")
1234.0
```

Answer (score 1):

your code is quite confused... to read a file that contains one float per line you can simply do:

```
val = map(float, open("test.txt"))
```

`val` will be a list containing your data with each element being a float

Comment: `val = [float(line) for line in open('test.txt')]` would be both clearer and more memory-efficient (because iterating through lines in a file doesn't read all the lines at once, unlike `readlines()`).

Comment: @benhoyt: You're right... I often end up using `L=open(xxx).readlines()` when I need to play with many lines at the same time and it's something that dangerously got to the finger level now.

Answer (score 0):

`ast.literal_eval()` will turn each line into tuples that you can then iterate or index for the values.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function `read_numbers()` which returns a list of lists of floats.

```
def read_numbers(filename):
    numbers = []
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            lst = [float(word) for word in line.split(',')]
            numbers.append(lst)
    return numbers
```

If your file contains:

```
1, 2
2, 3
7, 5
```

Then `read_numbers('filename')` would return:

```
[[1.0, 2.0], [2.0, 3.0], [7.0, 5.0]]
```

You may want to do error handling (or simply ignore errors) by expanding out the inner list comprehension and wrapping the call to `float()` in a `try ... except ValueError`.